# Ansible append multiple templates to a single file

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ansible, devops

How can I append multiple templates to a single file depending on a variable.

I have 3 variables vara, varb, varc. And their true/false determine whether I can use template1, template2, template3.

Their can be multiple permutations of these three files.

So what should be best strategy to append these templates in a single file.

Eg: if vara is true, varb is false, varc is true. 
Then output file should contain template1 and template3.

Answer (score 0):

If you are putting all of this in a single output file, you should only use one template, but put your if elsif logic in the template itself.

```
{% if vara == true %}
text1
{% elif varb == true %}
text2
{% elif varc == true %}
text3
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This would cause each template to be copied if its corresponding variable is true **without the need of extra Jinja2 templating**

```
- name: copy template
  template:
    src: "{{ item.name }}"
    dest: /my/dest/dir/
  when: item.state         ## this is a simplified version of "when item.state == True"
  loop:
    - vara_template: "{ name: 'template1', state: vara }"
    - varb_template: "{ name: 'template2', state: varb }"
    - varc_template: "{ name: 'template3', state: varc }"
```

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Eg: if vara is true, varb is false, varc is true. Then output file should contain template1 and template3."*

A: It's possible to use `lookup` and [`template`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/template.html#template-retrieve-contents-of-file-after-templating-with-jinja2) plugin. For example

```
shell> cat test.j2
{% if vara %}{{ lookup('template', 'template1.j2') }}{% endif %}
{% if varb %}{{ lookup('template', 'template2.j2') }}{% endif %}
{% if varc %}{{ lookup('template', 'template3.j2') }}{% endif %}

shell> cat template1.j2
vara: {{ vara }}

shell> cat template2.j2
varb: {{ varb }}

shell> cat template3.j2
varc: {{ varc }}
```

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    vara: true
    varb: false
    varc: true
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: test.j2
        dest: test.txt
```

give

```
shell> cat test.txt
vara: True
varc: True
```